# wildfly 10 (linux) Error: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Every derived table must have its own alias

Tags: genexus

Estou usando Genexus 15 U1.
Gerando o .war e executando do wildfly 10 (windows) funciona perfeitamente, porém, ao jogar no linux, no momento em que vai abrir a aplicação, temos o seguinte erro:

> 2016-11-07 12:17:09,626 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-14) UT005023: Exception handling request to /nfrr/servlet/com.sefaznfroraima.action: javax.servlet.ServletException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Every derived table must have its own alias
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:387)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:942)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3966)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3902)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2526)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2673)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2549)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1861)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1962)
>           at com.genexus.db.driver.GXDBMSmysql.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
>           at com.genexus.db.driver.GXPreparedStatement.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
>           at com.genexus.db.ForEachCursor.postExecute(Unknown Source)
>           at com.genexus.db.DataStoreProvider.execute(Unknown Source)
>           at com.genexus.db.DataStoreProvider.execute(Unknown Source)
>           at artech.security.api.gamloadrepositorycache.privateExecute(gamloadrepositorycache.java:65)
>           at artech.security.api.gamloadrepositorycache.execute_int(gamloadrepositorycache.java:58)
>           at artech.security.api.gamloadrepositorycache.execute(gamloadrepositorycache.java:45)
>           at artech.security.api.gamgetrepositoryconnection.privateExecute(gamgetrepositoryconnection.java:85)
>           at artech.security.api.gamgetrepositoryconnection.execute_int(gamgetrepositoryconnection.java:58)
>           at artech.security.api.gamgetrepositoryconnection.execute(gamgetrepositoryconnection.java:45)
>           at artech.security.api.getcurrentusername.privateExecute(getcurrentusername.java:58)
>           at artech.security.api.getcurrentusername.execute_int(getcurrentusername.java:49)
>           at artech.security.api.getcurrentusername.execute(getcurrentusername.java:40)
>           at artech.security.GAMUser.GetName(GAMUser.java:479)
>           at com.sefaznfroraima.SdtGAMUser.getname(SdtGAMUser.java:98)
>           at com.sefaznfroraima.action_impl.e11562(action_impl.java:727)

Servidor Wildfly 10
Genexus 15 U1
MySQL 5.5.52

Lembrando, o mesmo .war funciona no wildfly 10 windows.

Comment: Pelo erro me parece um erro de requisição ao servidor ou autenticação (presumo), a maquina linux tem acesso ao servidor Mysql?

Comment: olha o que identifiquei. Imagine o arquivo **app.war** <br />
quando executamos o deploy em alguns computadores, o select gerado é:  <br /><br />
select campo1, campo2 from tabela
<br /><br />
quando o mesmo arquivo é feito o deploy no servidor, o select gerado é:  <br /><br />
select * from (select campo1, campo2 from tabela)
<br/>
 <br />
e nessa subquery, ele nao coloca o alias. também já fizemos testes em outra maquina linux, e funciona normal.

Comment: Será que você subiu as configurações do servidor corretamente, ou será que esqueceu de subir algo?